# Generating XSL block in C#

Tags: c#, xslt

I am trying to generate the following XSL block in my C# application. Can anyone tell me how to to it?

```
<XSL-Script xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/......">
  <xsl:value-of select="$VAR">
</XSL-Script>
```

I tried to use regular C# XML class, and it removes the xsl: from the tag name, because it thinks xsl: is the namespace. And it also doesn't allow to use "$" in front of VAR for attribute value of "select".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user579242: This question is not clear. Please provide input sample, desired output, problematic stylesheet (or fragment) and platform details (XSLT processor, version, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a simple C# program that "generates" a complete XSLT stylesheet** and then performs this transformation on a "generated" XML document and outputs the result of the transformation to a file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

    class testTransform
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xslt = 
@"<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:variable name='vX' select='1'/>

<xsl:template match='/'>
 <xsl:value-of select='$vX'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

            string xml = @"<t/>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlDocument xslDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xslDoc.LoadXml(xslt);

            XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

            xslTrans.Load(xslDoc);

            xslTrans.Transform(xmlDoc, null, new StreamWriter("output.txt"));
        }
    }
```

**When this application is built and executed it creates a file named `"output.txt"` and its contents is the expected, correct result from the dynamically generated XSLT transformation**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>1
```